Can't remove text-decoration from <Link> component of Next.JS
I'm getting my hands dirty with Next.JS and having trouble removing the defauly text-decoration of <Link> component. I have a basic array of objects through which I'm mapping within a parent component to render card elements and I wrapped the whole card component around <Link> tags.
Here is my .tsx for the card component;
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { BestSellingCoursesType } from "@/types/bestSellingCourses";
import styles from "./BestSellingCoursesCard.module.scss";
import starIcon from "@/public/common/star.svg";

export const BestSellingCoursesCard: React.FC<BestSellingCoursesType> = ({
  title,
  category,
  categoryColor,
  categoryBgColor,
  price,
  thumbnail,
  review,
  registeredStudents,
}) => {
  return (
    <Link href="#" target="_blank" className={styles.courseCard}>
      <Image
        src={thumbnail}
        alt="instructor-profile-picture"
        width={244}
        height={183}
      />
      <div className={styles.cardInfo}>
        <div className={styles.categoryPriceRow}>
          <span
            className={styles.category}
            style={{ color: categoryColor, backgroundColor: categoryBgColor }}
          >
            {category}
          </span>
          <span className={styles.price}>${price}</span>
        </div>
        <p className={styles.title}>{title}</p>
        <div className={styles.ratingStudentsRow}>
          <span className={styles.ratingContainer}>
            <Image src={starIcon} alt="star-icon" />
            <span className={styles.rating}>{review.toString()}</span>
          </span>
          <span className={styles.registeredStudents}>
            <span className={styles.studentNumber}>
              {((registeredStudents - (registeredStudents % 100)) / 100 -
                (((registeredStudents - (registeredStudents % 100)) / 100) % 10)) /
                10}
              .{((registeredStudents - (registeredStudents % 100)) / 100) % 10}K
            </span>
            <span className={styles.students}>students</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

.scss file;
@use "../../app/_variables.scss" as *;

.courseCard {
  width: 244px;
  background-color: $white;
  .cardInfo {
    .categoryPriceRow {
      padding: 16px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      .category {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 6px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 500;
      }
      .price {
        color: $orange;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
    }
    .title {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 20px;
      letter-spacing: -0.01em;
      padding: 0 16px 16px 16px;
      color: $black;
    }
    .ratingStudentsRow {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 16px;
      border-top: 1px solid $iceBlue;
      .ratingContainer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 4px;
        .rating {
          color: $black;
        }
      }
      .registeredStudents {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 6px;
        .studentNumber {
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 500;
          color: $black;
        }
        .students {
          color: $gray;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Parent component;
import { BestSellingCoursesCard } from "../BestSellingCoursesCard/BestSellingCoursesCard";
import { BestSellingCoursesData } from "./BestSellingCoursesData";

import styles from "./BestSellingCourses.module.scss";

export const BestSellingCourses = () => {
  return (
    <section className={styles.bestSellingCourses}>
      <h1 className={styles.sectionTitle}>Best Selling Courses</h1>
      <div className={styles.courseCardsWrapper}>
        {BestSellingCoursesData.map((card) => {
          return (
            <BestSellingCoursesCard
              title={card.title}
              category={card.category}
              categoryColor={card.categoryColor}
              categoryBgColor={card.categoryBgColor}
              price={card.price}
              thumbnail={card.thumbnail}
              review={card.review}
              registeredStudents={card.registeredStudents}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

I'm also using SCSS for styling but somehow I cannot manage to remove the underlines. I have even tried inline styles, dev tools from the browser and I've checked this  issue but didn't work.

Here, you can see it doesn't even work this way.
I finally managed to solve by styling each child element of the cards wrapper container like
 .courseCardsWrapper * {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

However, it doesn't work when I style the card component. There is something always overwriting but I couldn't figure out because even !important cannot solve the issue.
